# PHP - How to create Multidimension Array by grouping same element from an array?

Tags: php, arrays

For example I have an array `$tempArr` that its element as shown :

```
Array
(
 [0] => 1
 [1] => 1
 [2] => 1
 [3] => 2
 [4] => 2
 [5] => 2
 [6] => 1
 [7] => 1
 [8] => 2
 [9] => 2
 [10] => 1
 ....
)
```

And I want to change it to a multidimensional array structure with same elements grouped together by sequence.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 2
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
    )
....
)
```

Please help. I've been working on it for few hours and still can't get it right.

Comment: Please show the code that you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very easy - just loop over the elements, and if the current element is different from the previous one - then you increase the index under which you will add the value to your output array.

```
$input = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1];

$output = [];
$idx = -1; // init with -1, so we get a start index of 0 after first increment
$prev = null; // init $prev with a value that won't be equal to the first
              // array value in any case
foreach($input as $val) {
    if($prev !== $val) {
        ++$idx;
    }
    $output[$idx][] = $val;
    $prev = $val; // set current item as new previous one
}

print_r($output);
```

https://3v4l.org/c2Irh